# How can I add write access to my pi user for folder?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, raspberry-pi, user-permissions, cifs

I wanted to mount a windows share on my raspberry pi and do some reading and writing to files in that folder.

I have successfully mounted it, even got it working with fstab

```
//192.168.10.99/Logs /mnt/NetworkLogs cifs user=Admin,pass=PASS,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

But my user pi does not seem to have access, and I've tried all kinds of black magic here...

```
sudo chmod 755 /mnt/NetworkLogs
sudo chown root /mnt/NetworkLogs
sudo chmod 755 /mnt/NetworkLogs
sudo chown -R pi:pi /mnt/NetworkLogs
```

Any idea? I probably did a `sudo mkdir NetworkLogs` in the mnt folder at one time.

Answer (score 0):

the rights on the partition must be given in fstab example:
`/dev/sdb5 /media/Storage fuseblk nofail,rw,nosuid,nodev,umask=022,gid=1000,uid=0` , another example given by the doc

```
/dev/sdb5 /media/Storage fuseblk nofail,rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions 0 0
```